# How does javascript control the timing of the click trigger event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a modal function, but there is a problem with this modal window, I don't know how to solve it~
That is when I click the right mouse button in the modal block, do not release the right mouse button, and move the mouse to the outer black area Releasing the right mouse button on the block will cause the modal window to close, but I want to adjust it so that the modal disappears only when the mouse is clicked on the black block, rather than the screen canceling when the mouse is released on the black block.

I am using jquery's click event to trigger. How should I change this?
In addition, how can I bind multiple trigger events? Currently, only click on confirm to close the modal. If I want to press Enter, I can also close the modal. How should I write it? ?

The above is the problem I encountered, I hope it can help me, a newbie to the program, thank you

```js
// click Modal
$("*[data-modal]").on("click", Modal);

// open Modal
function Modal() {
  $(".excel_popup").css("display", "flex");
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  //colse Modal
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (
      e.target.className == "close" ||
      e.target.className == "excel_popup" ||
      e.target.className == "btn_confirm" ||
      e.target.className == "btn_consider"
    ) {
      $("#js-job_excel_popup").css("display", "none");
      $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.excel_popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap {
  width: 360px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap header h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap header .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap .txt {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px 0px;
  color: #222;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap .btn_group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap .btn_group .btn_consider {
  width: 132px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-right: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap .btn_group .btn_consider:hover {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap .btn_group .btn_confirm {
  width: 132px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background-color: #222;
  margin-left: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
.excel_popup .excel_close_wrap .btn_group .btn_confirm:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="excel_export" id="js-excel_export" href="javascript:;" data-modal="js-job_excel_popup">
  <figure></figure>
  <p>clcik modal</p>
</a>

<div class="excel_popup" id="js-job_excel_popup" >
  <div class="excel_close_wrap">
    <header>
      <h2>title</h2>
      <div class="close" id="js-close">Ｘ</div>
    </header>
    <p class="txt">Hello World!!!</p>
    <div class="btn_group">
      <a class="btn_consider">Cancel</a>
      <a class="btn_confirm">Confirm</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you put the click listener for the document. Add the click listeners to the specific elements instead.

Comment: I made a little change, I changed the original captured document to capture excel_close_wrap,
but there is still a problem, because I hope that clicking on the outer black part can also make the Modal disappear, so it cannot disappear.

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/VwdjKbW?editors=1010

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I made a simple fix that actually solved the problem by just changing the click to mousedown.
Hope someone encounters this kind of problem can also refer to